# How to play hls streaming on xcode

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator

I am very new to xcode and I am trying to execute simple video app that will play hls url.

I googled and found one that plays a local video file. I tried if it will work with hls url (.m3u8) but it didn't

Here is the code I have so far.

```
-(IBAction)playvideo {
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]
pathForResource:@"http://mysite.com:1935/live/channel1/playlist.m3u8" ofType:@"mp4"]];
MPMoviePlayerViewController *playercontroller = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc]
initWithContentURL:url];
[self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:playercontroller];
playercontroller.moviePlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeFile;
[playercontroller.moviePlayer play];
playercontroller = nil;
}
```

I am getting this error.

```
VideoPlayTest[16276:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception     'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSURL initFileURLWithPath:]: nil string     parameter'
```

I am using latest xcode on mountain lion.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your URL to

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://mysite.com:1935/live/channel1/playlist.m3u8"];
```

Your other call is trying to pull the video out of the app's bundle, not the URL.

Comment: I'm getting ARC Semantic Issue. No Known Class Method for selector "URLwithString:"

Comment: Typed it on my iPad originally.  Updated answer.

Comment: Thanks.. error is gone now.. but video is not playing.. it goes to loading for a while and then goes back to home screen using simulator. Is it normal that it wont play in simulator?

Comment: Yep, you'll need to run it from the device.

Comment: thanks.. will have to wait for my account to get activated in dev.

Comment: You might need to change `playercontroller.moviePlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeFile;` to `playercontroller.moviePlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeStreaming;`